# SSL & Load Balancing

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-web-services, lamp

I use Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to route traffic between several web servers that host multiple websites (virtual hosts). The web servers act as front-ends (drones) and pull data off of shared NFS/DB servers.

To implement SSL on these websites, I know Amazon allows SSL Termination on the ELB to convert HTTPS requests to standard HTTP on the back-end. Does this work for multiple websites? Can you associate several SSL certificates with a single ELB?

Comment: An SSL certificate can be installed on more than one server, but you have to purchase a license for each server.

Comment: @Mircea: Bollocks.  I'd like to put it more pleasantly than that, but I simply cannot.

Comment: AFAIK, the ELB allows you to install the SSL certificate directly to it. My question is, what if there are several websites that need SSL certificates installed? Can you install more than one SSL certificate with an ELB?

Comment: @Mircea - I agree with womble. You need not purchase licenses to use SSL certificates.

Comment: Certain CA have terms and conditions stating you have to "license" the it certs for multiple servers. Obviously there is to technical reason, just t&c's. verisign is one example.

Comment: Entrust has a similar policy http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=5703

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't associate multiple SSL certificates because each SSL certificate requires it's own IP address (SNI?  Hah!) and you can only associate one IP address with each ELB.

Comment: How do people who host multiple websites on a server behind an ELB provide SSL? Do they create separate ELBs for each site?

Comment: That's exactly what they do.

Comment: I'm not sure how amazon does it, but we have 6 IP's as virtual Aliases on our linux box to act as a front end SSL server for 6 different certificates ( ie, eth0:0-eth0:5)we finally got smart on the last one, and did a wildcard cert.

Comment: I presume your Linux box isn't an EC2 instance, and not behind an ELB, and hence is irrelevant to this discussion.  AWS is different... so very, very different.

Comment: @womble Just doing some more thinking on this. Under this scenario, assume servers A/B are both identical web servers that are being Load Balanced. If I want to add HTTPS support for one of the sites on those servers, I create a new Load Balancer and forward all requests from port 80 on the ELB to port 80 on EC2 and on port 443 to port 80 (for SSL Termination). The virtual hosting should still work, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  ELB also supports SSL-to-the-backend, where the ELB will create a new SSL connection to your backend and use that, which I don't really see the point of, but some people get very excited about.

Comment: Yea I read about that. Seems like people were concerned about security within the Cloud (from ELB to EC2), but Amazon publicly announced that they're both behind hardware firewalls.

Comment: Anyone who's worried about network security "within the Cloud", but is still willing to put their data on hardware that someone else runs, is an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

If each hostname is under a single domain you can use a single wildcard certificate (e.g., *.example.com).

Comment: Unfortunately, they're all different top level domains.